# How to open Chromium Browser through Selenium ChromeDriver and Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I have a question.
I use a chromedriver of course, when I start my test, pycharm open Chromium, I would like to open Chrome, how I can change this ? Maybe I can set this in my code?

```
def setUp(self)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get("site")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Chromium Browser* have different version as follows:

- *Chrome Canary*
- Chrome from *Dev Channel*
- Raw build of *Chromium for Windows x64*

Not sure which *Chromium Browser* version you are trying to use.

However to use *Chrome Canary* version you can use the *ChromeOptions* and `binary_location` property through an instance of `Options()` class  to set the *absolute path* of the *Chrome Canary* binary and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.binary_location="C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Chrome_Canary]

---

### trivia

You need to download the latest *Chromium* binary from either of the official repositories:

- [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)
- [chromium.appspot](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)
- [Chrome Canary - Nightly build for developers](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/canary/)